# Calculate the variance for each element in the sample separately

Tags: pandas, variance

I had DF with name of attraction, date and ride sum.

```
import pandas as pd

attr = pd.DataFrame(
    {'rides':['circuit','circuit',
              'roller coaster', 'roller coaster',
              'car', 'car', 'car',
              'train', 'train'],
    'date':['2019-06-22', '2019-06-23',
            '2019-06-29', '2019-07-06',
            '2019-09-01', '2019-09-07', '2019-09-08',
            '2019-09-14', '2019-09-15'],
    'ride_sum':[663, 483,
                858, 602,
                326, 2, 86,
                70, 134]})

    rides           date        ride_sum
0   circuit         2019-06-22  663
1   circuit         2019-06-23  483
2   roller coaster  2019-06-29  858
3   roller coaster  2019-07-06  602
4   car             2019-09-01  326
5   car             2019-09-07  2
6   car             2019-09-08  86
7   train           2019-09-14  70
8   train           2019-09-15  134
```

I can calculate this manually, but my dataframe has more than 1000 lines and more than 30 different rides.

In the example, it looks like this

```
print(attr.loc[attr['rides'] == 'circuit']['ride_sum'].var(),
      attr.loc[attr['rides'] == 'roller coaster']['ride_sum'].var(),
      attr.loc[attr['rides'] == 'car']['ride_sum'].var(),
      attr.loc[attr['rides'] == 'train']['ride_sum'].var())

16200.0 32768.0 28272.0 2048.0
```

I want to get a dataframe with a variance for each rides that looks like this

```
    rides           var
0   circuit         16200.0
1   roller coaster  32768.0
2   car             28272.0
3   train           2048.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `groupby` together with `var()` like this:

```
attr.groupby("rides").var().reset_index()


rides   ride_sum
0   car 28272
1   circuit 16200
2   roller coaster  32768
3   train   2048
```

(`reset_index()` is not necessarily required)

Comment: Thank you! How can i do this for kurtosis? if I try to replace it, I get 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'kurtosis'

Comment: For kurtosis see the edited answer of @Serge de Gosson de Varennes. As an addition to that you could use `scipy.stats.kurtosis` in the `apply` method.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
attr.groupby(attr.rides).agg(["var"]).reset_index()
```

**EDIT:**

For kurtosis, there is no aggregate. You need to do this:

```
attr.groupby(attr.rides).apply(pd.DataFrame.kurt).reset_index()
```

With your example, there are fewer than three values per group, so it'll return `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you! How can i do this for kurtosis? if I try to replace it, I get ''SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'kurtosis"

Answer (score 0):

Use the function unique in pandas to take unique rides and apply a loop for to take var
Example:

```
unique_rides = unique(attr['rides'])

for ride in unque_rides:
    print(attr.loc[attr['rides'] == ride]['ride_sum'].var())
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you! How can i get the results in the dict?